# Python - Given list of dates (as strings), how do we return only those that fall within last 365 days?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing, filtering

Given the following list of strings

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np


strings = ['Nov 1 2021', 'Oct 25 2021', 'Oct 18 2021', 'Oct 11 2021', 'Oct 4 2021', 'Sep 27 2021',
                'Sep 20 2021', 'Aug 24 2021', 'Aug 16 2021', 'Aug 9 2021', 'Aug 2 2021', 'Jul 26 2021',
                'Jun 28 2021', 'Jun 21 2021', 'Jun 14 2021', 'Jun 7 2021', 'May 24 2021', 'May 10 2021',
                'May 3 2021', 'Apr 26 2021', 'Apr 12 2021', 'Apr 12 2021', 'Apr 5 2021', 'Mar 22 2021',
                'Feb 22 2021', 'Feb 13 2021', 'Feb 8 2021', 'Feb 1 2021', 'Nov 2 2020', 'Sep 28 2020',
                'Aug 31 2020', 'Aug 20 2020', 'Aug 10 2020', 'Jun 29 2020', 'Jun 22 2020', 'Jun 15 2020',
                'Mar 2 2020', 'Feb 10 2020', 'Feb 3 2020', 'Jan 27 2020', 'Jan 20 2020', 'Jan 13 2020',
                'Jan 6 2020', 'Aug 26 2019', 'Aug 5 2019', 'Jul 29 2019', 'Jul 22 2019', 'Jul 15 2019']
```

What's the most efficient way to return a list of those dates that fall within the last 365 days?

Here's my failed attempt:

```
# Converts strings to datetime format and appends to new list, 'dates.'

dates = []
for item in strings:
    convert_string = datetime.strptime(item, "%b %d %Y").date()
    dates.append(convert_string)


# Given each item in 'dates' list returns corresponding
# list showing elapsed time between each item and today (Nov 11th 2021).

elapsed_time = []
def dateDelta(i):
    today = datetime.fromisoformat(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).date()
    date = i
    delta = (today - date).days
    elapsed_time.append(delta)

for i in dates:
    dateDelta(i)


# Concatenates 'dates' list and 'elapsed_times_list' in attempt to somehow connect the two.

date_and_elapsed_time = []
date_and_elapsed_time.append(dates)
date_and_elapsed_time.append(elapsed_time)


# Takes 'elapsed_time list' appends only the dates that fall within the last 365 days.

relevant_elapsed_time_list = []
for i in elapsed_time:
    if i <= 365:
        relevant_elapsed_time_list.append(i)


# Finds indices of 'relevant_elapsed_time_list' within last 365 days.
# After trawling StackOverflow posts, I import numpy in an effort to help with indexing.
# My thinking is I can use the indices of the relevant elapsed times from the
# 'elapsed_time_list' and return the corresponding date from the 'dates' list.

relevant_elapsed_time_list_indices = []
for item in relevant_elapsed_time_list:
    indexes = []
    for index, sub_lst in enumerate(date_and_elapsed_time):
        try:
            indexes.append((index, sub_lst.index(item)))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    relevant_elapsed_time_list_indices.append(indexes)

relevant_elapsed_time_list_indices = np.array([[x[0][0], x[0][1]] for x in relevant_elapsed_time_list_indices])
```

At this point, I'm as yet unable to convert the `relevant_elapsed_time_list_indices` list to the corresponding indices for the first sub-list in `date_and_elapsed_time`. The point of this would be to then isolate those indices (i.e. dates).

What's the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want 365 days specifically or a year?

Comment: Yes I wanted 365 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the strings to datetime objects using [`.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), then use a conditional list comprehension that uses `timedelta` to pick ones that fall within the last 365 days:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_365_days = [s for s in strings if datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d %Y") + timedelta(days=365) >= datetime.today()]
```

Alternatively you can compute the cutoff date in advance:

```
cutoff = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365)
last_365_days = [s for s in strings if datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d %Y") >= cutoff]
```

The value of `last_365_days` should then be (for today):

```
['Nov 1 2021', 'Oct 25 2021', 'Oct 18 2021', 'Oct 11 2021', 'Oct 4 2021',
 'Sep 27 2021', 'Sep 20 2021', 'Aug 24 2021', 'Aug 16 2021', 'Aug 9 2021',
 'Aug 2 2021', 'Jul 26 2021', 'Jun 28 2021', 'Jun 21 2021', 'Jun 14 2021',
 'Jun 7 2021', 'May 24 2021', 'May 10 2021', 'May 3 2021', 'Apr 26 2021',
 'Apr 12 2021', 'Apr 12 2021', 'Apr 5 2021', 'Mar 22 2021', 'Feb 22 2021',
 'Feb 13 2021', 'Feb 8 2021', 'Feb 1 2021']
```

Comment: I am in awe of how efficient this solution is (as compared to what I had attempted). As a new student of Python, I really appreciate your response!